# jQuery "if" to change text

Tags: jquery, html

Should this work, or am I doing something completely wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="header-title">
<h1 class="h1-title" id='title'>America</h1>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#title').click(function(){
    var classExist = $(this).hasClass('active-t');
    if(classExist = false) {
        $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>'Murica!</h1>");
    }
    if(classExist = true) {
        $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>America</h1>");
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/859a8gmd/3/)

Anyways, I cant get it to work

Comment: compare with `==` not with assignment `=` and you can do without comparision for boolean types like `if(classExist)`.  You can reduce your code to `$('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>"+($(this).hasClass('active-t')?'Murica!':'America')+"</h1>");`

Comment: your jsfiddle does not have jquery activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `===` when checking for `true` or `false`. Also, why not simplify to just alter the `text()`?

Added `toggleClass` because I think that is what you are trying to do.

```
$('#title').click(function () {
    var classExist = $(this).hasClass('active-t');
    if (!!classExist) {
        $(this).text("'Murica!");
    } else {
        $(this).text('America');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active-t');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/859a8gmd/10/)

Comment: This kind of works, but I also want it so that when you click the "'Murica!" it will change back to "America"

Comment: It does, I added the `$(this).toggleClass('active-t');` to the function.

Answer (score 5):

You can simple:

```
 $('#title').click(function() {
   $(this).hasClass('active-t') ? $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>America</h1>") : $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>'Murica!</h1>");

 });
```

Comment: On a side note, it might be unnecessary to completely replace the div element using the `$.html()` function.  If you're just changing text, you could use something like `$(".h1-title").text("'Murica!");` instead.

Comment: Tried it, and it only works from "America" to "'Murica!", not the other way again

EDIT: using `.text` it makes the "'Murica!" formating go south

Comment: Because you don't set `active-t` class anywhere. Take a look here [codepen](http://codepen.io/Chariz/pen/Pwwaoq). Also change it to use `text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 4):

```
if(classExist = false) {
    $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>'Murica!</h1>");
}
if(classExist = true) {
    $('.header-title').html("<h1 class='h1-title'>America</h1>");
}
```

These are assignment statements, not comparisons. Use `===` instead of `=`

Also, you didn't specify to load jquery in your fiddle.

Comment: Updated fiddle, but still, only works from "America" to "'Murica!", and not the other way

Comment: Booleans are not meant to be compared anyway; `if( !classExist ) { .. } .. if( classExist ) { ... }` suffices.